# Is there a term for this concept (Randomly Random)?

Tags: terminology, randomness

Let's say I have what appears to be a fair dice that over 10K fair throws it produces very close to 1/6 occurrences of each face value.  But then one day it starts a string of throws where the 3 face occurs 1/4 of the time for a run of a few thousand throws. And then one day it reverts to the expected 1/6 probability distribution for a few more thousand throws.  And then it starts returning 1/5 distribution for 1's for a few thousand throws before once again returning to the expected 1/6 distribution for a fair dice.

Is there a term for this concept or something similar?

Comment: Think of it as you are drawing a dice at random from a set of dice and then throwing the dice. In your case, you are choosing this dice after some thousand throws.

Comment: This is an example of "nonstationarity" of a stochastic process.

Comment: Thanks https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber.  The term nonstationary seems to be the concept I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a scenario that could arise in many cases. However, this is a broad class of phenomena and I don't believe there is a single term for it (your description of this as "randomly random" is not in use, nor is it very precise or accurate).

Essentially, what you have have described empirically could be a number of studied statistical models

- Broadly, there is a time series $X_t$ of random variables, each of which has some number of samples drawn independently, and whose parameters may (or may not) change from $t$ to $t+1$ in some unknown way. In your case each $X$ is a multinomial distribution (i.e. a single dice row) whose probabilities $p_k^t$ for $k = 1...6$ are not necessarily identical for each $t$; each $t$ could correspond to a single dice throw (once per second or minute), so that each $X_t$ is sampled from only once; or each $t$ could represent a longer length of time (like a day) with many independently drawn samples. The precise relationship between $p_k^t$ and $p_k^{t+1}$ depends on lot on extra unspecified details of the model. Perhaps there is no relationship, and each $p_k^t$ is sampled independently from some sort of Dirichlet distribution; perhaps this is a Markov model, where $p_k^t$ at some time t has a certain probability of transforming into some new dice roll probabilities $p_k^{t+1}$; or perhaps this this is some sort of regression model where the time $t$ is a covariate and the probabilities $p_k^t$ are some parametrized function of $t$.
- Alternatively, there could be a single random variable $X$, representing the probabilities for a dice roll independent of all previous rolls, but your samples (dice rolls) are not all independent, but instead correlated in time for some unknown reason (i.e. rolling a 4 once makes it slightly more likely for a 4 to be rolled the next time). This models also bears some resemblance to a special case of a Markov model (e.g. there is some latent variable representing the dice rolls current bias, which can shift over time as different rolls occur, but the process is stationary and in the long term the dice roll rates tend to some fixed probabilities).

Answer (score 0):

Per this [educational source](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40037-016-0256-6) to quote:

> Means, correlation coefficients, and other sample findings tend to be imprecise estimates of the corresponding population parameters of interest when sample sizes are small [1]. As recognized by most researchers, small samples tend to have very limited statistical power for detecting population differences (e.g., between groups) and relations (i.e., between variables) of interest. That is, even if a rather substantial difference or relation exists in the population from which we sample, small samples often fail to obtain a statistically significant difference or relation. Consequently, using small samples, we will often fail to reject the null hypothesis of no difference or no relation when that null hypothesis is not true. This testing error is called a Type II error [1], familiar to most researchers. So when a small sample size produces a significant difference, researchers erroneously conclude, ignoring the possibility of Type II error, that the difference must reflect a real effect.

So, I would refer to your term "randomly random" as perhaps more  appropriately a case of "limited statistical power" observed in small sample situations. The author of the referenced work also cites the occurrence of associated Type II error as well in small samples.

I believe researchers are not alone in this erroneous behavior, as having some experience in playing the card game Omaha where the players gets four cards played in conjunction with community cards (dealt face-up) where some strange small sample results can occur. I apparently actually managed to obtain a flush 3 hands in a role, not that there were many believers on the 3rd event. The version of Omaha allowed making a bet the size of all placed bets (so-called pot-limit), which I did. As I was suspected surely this time of bluffing, my caller re-raised the pot (so four times the original pot) to which I re-raised that pot (I did possess the 2nd highest possible flush and suspected that this was but a test of my hands strength, so I re-raised again making this, in effect, all your money (all-in) wager. I, to the great disbelief of my caller, did possess a higher flush. Note, I used his knowledge of odds against him, believing he would feel confident even without a very high flush. Lesson: because something, in the short run, is highly unlikely, don't over bet against it.